# Get ClientId of control in Repeater

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

The repeater fires the event when Item is created

```
 Protected Sub Repeater1_ItemCreated(sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles Repeater1.ItemCreated
```

And it is possible to catch and modify the control on this single data row.

```
Dim lnk As HyperLink = CType(e.Item.FindControl("lblShipmentDetails"), HyperLink)
```

Now the problem is, that for any JavaScript, it is needed to determine the correct client ID. But the control does not hold the Client ID, just the `lblShipmentDetails` String.

What MSDN says:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d04y8ss%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

or CodeProject:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/108887/Client-Ids-Generation-with-ASP-NET

But how to catch the correct ClientID from Repeater to use it in JavaScript ?

[image: ClientDi]

Source is generated with auto-id. How to get this id?
[image: Auto Id]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `DataBound` Event. To get the control ID, the repeater needs to bind data first. Then just ask for ID as in the `Created` event.

```
    Protected Sub Repeater1_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles Repeater1.ItemDataBound
    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
        Dim btn As Button = CType(e.Item.FindControl("btnOrderTrackingConfirmMove"), Button)
        If btn IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim RealId As String = btn.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btn, String.Empty).ToString

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```